# How to give scrapy spider a new task only once the current one has received a response from the server

Tags: python, scrapy

I have a list of entries in a database that each corresponds to some scraping task. Only once one is finished, do I want the spider to continue to the next one. Here is some pseudocode that gives the idea of what I want to do though it is not exactly what I want because it uses a while loop creating a massive backlog of entries waiting to be processed.

```
def start_requests(self):
    while True:
        rec = GetDocumentAndMarkAsProcessing()
        if rec == None:
            break;
        script = getScript(rec)
        yield SplashRequest(..., callback=self.parse, endpoint="execute",
                args={
                    'lua_source': script
                }
              )

def parse(self, response):
    ... store results in database ...
```

How can I make scrapy work on the next entry only when it has received a response from the previous SplashRequest for the previous entry?

I am not sure if simple callback functions would be enough to do the trick or if I need something more sophisticated.

Answer (score 1):

All I needed to do was explicitly call another request with yield in the parse function with parse as the callback itself. So in the end I have something like this:

```
def start_requests(self):
    rec = GetDocumentAndMarkAsProcessing()
    script = getScript(rec)
    yield SplashRequest(..., callback=self.parse, endpoint="execute",
            args={
                'lua_source': script
            }
          )

def parse(self, response):
    ... store results in database ...
    rec = GetDocumentAndMarkAsProcessing()
    script = getScript(rec)
    yield SplashRequest(..., callback=self.parse, endpoint="execute",
            args={
                'lua_source': script
            }
          )
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you might be able to achieve this by setting CONCURRENT_REQUESTS to 1 in your settings.py. That will make it so the crawler only sends one request at a time, although I admit I am not sure how the timing works on the second request - whether it sends it when the callback is finished executing or when the response is retrieved.

Comment: Hmm this may have worked as well. In the end I came up with a solution that I posted. It was simpler than I thought. Before the other things I had tried were not working because I had not been explicitly calling the yield command.